# Laravel 8 - relationship return null

Tags: php, html, laravel

I have one more relationship in the project like this it works but this is not working. I can't see any value on the screen. It return null. I'm not good with Laravel and relationships in database. I think my controller and routes are correct but my relationships are incorrent.

**My User model contains the following relationship:**

```
public function follows(){
    return $this->hasMany('App\Models\Follow');
}
```

**My Follow model contains the following relationship:**

```
public function user(){
    return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User');
}
```

**My blade is:**

```
@foreach ($user->follows as $followr)
    <h6><strong>{{$followr}}</strong></h6>
@endforeach
```

Comment: please provide your table structures, it generally is because you do not define primary key or foreign key as Laravel expected

Answer (score 0):

please refer laravel eloquent documentation [here](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/eloquent-relationships)

you can pass foreign key and local key as 2nd and 3rd arguement in hasMany function and pass foreign key and owner key as 2nd and 3rd arguement in belongsTo function